# How to run a multinomial logistic regression with mixed effects in R?

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multinomial-logit

I'm trying to run a multinomial logistic regression with mixed effects. Let's say I have the following variables:

Participant (ten participants, each with 10 observations)
Word (ten different words, each participant sees each once)
IV (some two level grouping variable)
DV (can be 1, 2 or 3)

How would I run a multinomial logistic regression with ppt and word as random variables?

Here is some sample data:

```
ppt <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
word <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
IV <- rep(1:2, times = 50)
DV <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(ppt, word, IV, DV))
```

Comment: The package `mclogit` seems to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think one way to do this is with the `glmnet` package,

> glmnet: Lasso and Elastic-Net Regularized Generalized Linear Models.
> Extremely efficient procedures for fitting the entire lasso or elastic-net regularization path for linear regression, **logistic and multinomial regression** models, Poisson regression, Cox model, multiple-response Gaussian, and the grouped multinomial regression.

You need to install `glmnet` and its dependencies first, and R compiles a lot of C/C++ code to do this.

```
ppt <- rep(1:10, each = 10)
word <- rep(1:10, times = 10)
IV <- rep(1:2, times = 50)
DV <- sample(x = c(1,2,3), size = 100, replace = TRUE)

d <- as.data.frame(cbind(ppt, word, IV, DV))

# basic usage:
library(glmnet)  
fit <- glmnet(as.matrix(d[,1:3]), d$DV, family = "multinomial")
summary(fit)
```

Maybe ask this at stats.stackexchange.com, the real experts are over there.

Comment: `glmnet` to my knowledge does not incorporate random effects, and it tries to remove variables which would not be a good idea in this (and most other) context.

Comment: Thanks I was indeed not sure. That question was asked in a different forum, and the example was a toy example.

Comment: Binary logistic regression is easier to do than multinomial logistic regression, and binary regression requires 96 participants just to estimate the overall intercept.  So I don't know how this project is going to work with 10 participants.  Categorical outcome variables have minimum information.